# How to export polygon-wise average value of NDVI in Earth Engine?

Tags: export, google-earth-engine, ndvi

I need the average NDVI value for some sample fields of a specific crop. I have the boundary polygons in a shapefile and imported it in the earth engine as fusion table. I have also calculated the NDVI for the whole tile. Now I want to get average NDVI value for each sample fields.The sample fields are numbered as 1,2,3,...18.  Being a begginer, I am stuck here how to get the values or export the NDVI image for whole tile so that i can use it in other offline softwares. I was wondering could you please help me out in this regard. [image]

Comment: Please include the code of what you have done so far. Do you need help with the export or with the calculation of the average values?